# Use PHP value as function name to get dynamic function

Tags: php, function, concatenation

Ok, it would be pretty long to explain why I need this, but the reality is that..., I need this to work that way. I need to actually use a dynamic PHP value (a kind of unique string in my database) as a function name, but I can't get it to work as I would like.

Here is a little snippet of what I would like to do;

```
$dynamic_value = "t7duHJH783js7js83"; //from Database, unique ID
function file_.$dynamic_value.(){ ... }
```

So here, the function name would be like this;

```
function file_t7duHJH783js7js83(){ ... }
```

I'm in a while loop, there could be 3 results or 35, so naming them in a unique manner like this will make the code work inside of ceasing to work after the first row because the function name is simply **file_** instead of **file_t7duHJH783js7js83**, by repeating itself, it stops.

I know, some people would say don't do this, but I have no choice, this is the only way for me to make my script work and it would be tedious to explain.

Thanks a lot for your help and comprehension.

Comment: Did you try eval?

Comment: When `eval()` seems appropriate, often the script needs a rethink.

Comment: Since this is going to have some code manually I think because the function is only dynamic and being called based on the ids of the database, I think you can do just one function, pass the string as an argument and then inside do a switch case to every function available: `function file($id) { switch($id) { case 't7duHJH...': break; ... } }` ...you actually have choices but well, you know.  Or you can use the `$function()` instead (in your case `$dynamic_value(){ }` and that's it, you can't as I know, do this concatenation thing for dynamic creation.)